# Get the value of textblocks inside Listview itemtemplate in windows 8 store app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I dynamically populate a listview with XAML like below

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="templateTrending" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock x:Name="questionBlock" Text="{Binding Path=ques}" Margin="20" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="categoryBlock" Text="{Binding Path=categ}" Margin="20"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="userBlock" Text="{Binding Path=user}" Margin="20"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Now in the listviewselection changed method I need to get the values of the textblocks and pass to next  XAML page.I tried [Jerry Nixon's method](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html) but am not able to figure it out.Then I tried [wpf method](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/29ecc8ee-26ee-4331-8f97-35ff9d3e6886/how-to-access-items-in-a-datatemplate-for-wpf-listview) that too didn't work out.So how to achieve this.And below is the code how I assigned the value to the list view

```
public class Product
{
    public string Question { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string User { get; set; }
}
```

And adding it the list view as below

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Questions").Include("user");
IEnumerable<ParseObject> res = await query.FindAsync();

List<Product> list = new List<Product>();
foreach (var i in res)
{
    var u = i.Get<ParseUser>("user").Username;
    var q = i.Get<string>("question");
    var c = i.Get<string>("category");
    list.Add(new Product
    {
        Question = q,
        Category = c,
        User = u,
    });
}
listTrending.ItemsSource = list;
```

Am getting the data from parse.com backend.And my selected item code as below

```
private void listTrending_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string Qpass = listTrending.SelectedItem.ToString();
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(WallScreen), Qpass);
}
```

And the code under onnvaigated to method as below

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameter != null)
    {
        textQuestion.Text = e.Parameter.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        textQuestion.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: And yes am trying to get the value of listview selected item. As of now am getting the output as myappname.Screens.wallscreen.Product

Comment: So for the above code I want to pass the value of questionBlock in listview selected item to textQuestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking at it the wrong way. If you are trying to get the values of a selected item and the values are displayed in UI using bindings - you can extract these values from the binding source which in your case is the `listTrending.SelectedItem` - you just need to cast it to `Product`.

Comment: I want to get the value of each textblock in each variable,and pass the value to Textblocks in next screen .But am getting the output as myappname.Screens.wallscreen+Product

Comment: Replace `string  qPass = listTrending.SelectedItem.ToString();` with something like `string user = ((Product)listTrending.SelectedItem).user`. Also make sure your property names start with an uppercase letter unless their names need to match some json object property names, since that's a very strong industry standard naming convention in C#.

Comment: Alternatively override the `ToString()` method on the `Product` type to return what you need and then `listTrending.SelectedItem.ToString()` should return that value. Also make sure you handle `listTrending.SelectedItem == null` cases.

Comment: it WORKED!!!! Phew!!  Thank you Filip Skakun,thanks a ton! I was scratching my head for hours for this simple code!

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the code for your selection changed event handler. I am not sure I uderstand what you are trying to do because if all you are trying to do is get the contents of the selected item it is as easy as this:

```
    private void myListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            Product p = e.AddedItems[0] as Product;
        }
    }
```

Comment: And the value of p i got is myappname.Screens.wallscreen+Product

Comment: try changing your code above to "string  qPass = ((Product)(listTrending.SelectedItem)).ques;"

Comment: Thanks Jon. Filip Skakun and you helped me .